# How can I get an enum of all ligatures named in Material Icon?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using `mat-icon` in an Angular project and it takes ligature names in the element content, such as `warning`, `error`, `home`, `brightness_1`, etc.

I can't find a comprehensive list of those names anywhere except Google's [font browser](https://fonts.google.com/icons?icon.set=Material+Icons) for it. That's fine for searching every time I need something, but I want to stick all of the ligatures in a TypeScript enum and have them available as string constants right there for my IDE to suggest. I can easily scrape that page and map the labels to an enum and copy and paste, but I don't want to have to do that every time icons are added.

How can I get a list of all of the named ligatures that's kept up to date when the font is updated?

Comment: If you use VS Code you can use a plugin https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Archety.material-icons

Comment: That's a good way to insert SVG data for the icons, but not quite what I'm looking for. I'd like to be able to use the named ligatures instead of copying the vector data all over the place.